# Returning the result from dispatch to a component throws "undefined" exception

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux, dispatch

I have the following method inside the data-operations `tsx` file:

```
export function EnrollStudent(student, courseId) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(enrollUserBegin());

    axios
      .post("api/Course/EnrollStudent/" + courseId + "/" + student.id)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data === 1) {
          dispatch(enrollUserSuccess(student, courseId));

          console.log("Student is enrolled.");
          toast.success("Student is enrolled successfully.", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
          });
        } else {
          dispatch(enrollUserSuccess(null, 0));
          console.log("Failed to enroll.");
          toast.warn(
            "Failed to enroll the student. Possible reason: Already enrolled.",
            {
              position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
            }
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(enrollUserFailure(error));

        toast.warn("An error occurred. Please contact the Admin.", {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
        });
      });
  };
}
```

This method is called from another component by a button click:

```
const enroll_onClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const currentUserId = authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"];
  var student: any = { id: currentUserId };
  props.enrollStudent(student, st_courseId);
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
            enrollStudent: (student, courseId) => dispatch(EnrollStudent(student, courseId)),
        }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(CourseEnrollmentWithCode);
```

This works fine and the database is updated properly. But, I want to get the result of the `enrollStudent`and perform an action (e.g., navigate to another page).

I tried this but I received `props.enrollStudent() is undefined` error.

```
props.enrollStudent(student, st_courseId)
.then(() => {
    console.log("enrolld");
    history.push('/courses');
 });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you mistyped the name of the function. props.enrollStudent should be props.EnrollStudent. At least this is how this function appears here in the definition.

Comment: @i.brod thanks for the comment. I rename it to `enrollStudent` in `mapDispatchToProps` method. I updated my code.

Comment: And does it work..?

Comment: @i.brod without `.then` it works.

Comment: So `EnrollStudent()` is a function that returns a function ...

Comment: And the returned function, same as any function, does nothing unless it is executed. And even if it is executed, it returns `undefined` so, whichever way you look at it, chaining `.then()` is bound to throw.

Comment: What kind of redux middleware are you using?

Comment: Can you show the component that `enroll_onClick` is declared in? There is no reference to `props` in `enroll_onClick`.

Comment: when using axios. To make the wrapper function promise based you'd have to return axios. 
someFunction() {  return axios.get();}

Then you can do someFunction().then(res => {});
If any part of that wrapper function is not promise based this will not work

Answer (score 4):

By looking at the code, I'm guessing you are using the `redux-thunk` middleware.

In the `EnrollStudent` function, you have to add a `return` statement before `axios` (line 5) so that your thunk function (the function returned by `EnrollStudent`) returns a promise.

Take a look at the examples here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk, especially the `makeASandwichWithSecretSauce` function.

Answer (score 2):

**You must not use promises in action creators** ... you can only return an action object ... https://redux.js.org/api/store/

In this case (side effects) **you have to use a middleware** (`redux-thunk`, `redux-promise`, `redux-saga`) ... https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware/

If middleware not used ... current behaviour (looking as partially working) is **at least missleading**.

Comment: Given the provided code, he is definitely using the redux-thunk middleware.